# I can build but not archive my app

Tags: xcode, swift, build, archive

Swift.
I can build my app in xcode, it works perfectly, but when I try to archive, I see this error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Comment: Is there something else in the build log before that line?

Comment: Cmd + K (clean) and try again.